# Send img to server

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio, mobile

I try send image (after capture) to server via mobilephone (android)
To do this i use php script (its uploaded on server)
And JAVA code to post image.

The URL of php script:
http://nwstudio.esy.es/AndroidFileUpload/uploads/fileUpload.php

On mobile after click button for upload i see only small empty window without text of error or anything (there should be msg about upload)

What i do wrong? ;/

PHP:

```
<?php

// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "uploads/";

// array for final json respone
$response = array();

// getting server ip address
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

// final file url that is being uploaded
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'AndroidFileUpload' . '/' . $target_path;


if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    // reading other post parameters
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $website = isset($_POST['website']) ? $_POST['website'] : '';

    $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $response['email'] = $email;
    $response['website'] = $website;

    try {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            // make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
        }

        // File successfully uploaded
        $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // File parameter is missing
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}

// Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

JAVA:

```
package com.nkdroid.tinderswipe;

/**
 * Created by Haze on 15.08.2016.
 */

import com.nkdroid.tinderswipe.AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class UploadActivity extends Activity {

    // LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = TakePhotoActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String filePath = null;
    private TextView txtPercentage;
    private ImageView imgPreview;
    private VideoView vidPreview;
    private Button btnUpload;
    long totalSize = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        txtPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
        btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        vidPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);

        // Receiving the data from previous activity
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
        filePath = i.getStringExtra("filePath");

        // boolean flag to identify the media type, image or video
        boolean isImage = i.getBooleanExtra("isImage", true);

        if (filePath != null) {
            // Displaying the image or video on the screen
            previewMedia(isImage);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry, file path is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // uploading the file to server
                new UploadFileToServer().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Displaying captured image/video on the screen
     * */
    private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {
        // Checking whether captured media is image or video
        if (isImage) {
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vidPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            vidPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vidPreview.setVideoPath(filePath);
            // start playing
            vidPreview.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Uploading the file to server
     * */
    private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // setting progress bar to zero
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // Making progress bar visible
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // updating progress bar value
            progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

            // updating percentage value
            txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile() {
            String responseString = null;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

            try {
                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });

                File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

                // Adding file data to http body
                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

                // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
                entity.addPart("website",
                        new StringBody("www.androidhive.info"));
                entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("abc@gmail.com"));

                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Server response
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                            + statusCode;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }

            return responseString;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

            // showing the server response in an alert dialog
            showAlert(result);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method to show alert dialog
     * */
    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

JAVA config:

```
package com.nkdroid.tinderswipe;

/**
 * Created by Haze on 15.08.2016.
 */

public class Config {

    // File upload url (replace the ip with your server address)
    public static final String FILE_UPLOAD_URL = "http://http://nwstudio.esy.es/AndroidFileUpload/uploads/fileUpload.php";

    // Directory name to store captured images and videos
    public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "AndroidFileUpload";
}
```

Comment: `private void previewMedia` Why are you poating that code? What has it to do with uploading a file? Please post as little code as possible.

Comment: try this http://harshalbenake.blogspot.in/2016/04/hb-blog-108-file-upload-to-server-in.html

Comment: About this previewMedia, its for video (i dont use this for now, maybe in next patch of app).I just dont delete this for now :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to don't use AsyncTask for this purpose. Instead of AsyncTask try send image with [Retrofit 2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

**UPDATE**

This is my project [Retrofit2Sample](https://github.com/MrOnyszko/Retrofit2Sample) that shows usage of *Retrofit 2*. I believe that it'll help to understand how it work and show how to work with this awesome rest client.